# How to clean up function that is outside useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, settimeout, code-cleanup

I have a resend code button and will disable it for 30sec after pressed. Here is my function.

```
    const time = useRef(30);

    function disableResendBtn() {
        time.current = 30;
        setsendCodeBtnDisabled(true);
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            (time.current = time.current - 1),
                setsendCodeBtnText(i18n.t('RESEND') + '(' + time.current + ')'),
                console.log(time.current);
        }, 1000);
        setTimeout(() => {
            setsendCodeBtnDisabled(false);
            setsendCodeBtnText(i18n.t('RESEND'));
            clearInterval(interval);
        }, 30000);
    }
```

I am getting a error of `Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in %s.%s, a useEffect cleanup function` when I move on to next page. This error is not showing everytime. So I am confused whether setInterval/setTimeout function is the reason.

Anyway, how I can use the useEffect to clean up that? The function is not inside useEffect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the `setInterval`'s and `setTimeout`'s return value in a ref and then create an empty `useEffect` which will then clean up those for you.

There is a simpler way that I can think of. Instead of tracking these intervals and timeouts and then cleaning up using an empty `useEffect`, you can just create a `useEffect` which updates the current time every second. And, to track the disabled state, you can create another state which tracks "until when the button should be disabled".

```
export default function App() {
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = React.useState(Date.now());
  const [disabledUntil, setDisabledUntil] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setCurrentTime(Date.now());
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  const onClick = () => {
    // disable button for 30 seconds
    setDisabledUntil(Date.now() + 30 * 1000);
  };

  const buttonDisabledSeconds = Math.floor(
    (disabledUntil - currentTime) / 1000
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClick} disabled={currentTime < disabledUntil}>
        Send
      </button>
      <p>
        {buttonDisabledSeconds >= 0 &&
          `Button disabled for ${buttonDisabledSeconds} seconds`}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This way, the `cleanup` is very close to the actual interval definition.